# How can I reduce how much a flat roof heats my house?

Tags: insulation, roof

My flat roof is insulated with wool, but still it's heating up my room considerably. The situation is much better in the rest of the house.

Any ideas how to do a quick fix?

The roof is currently blackish so I think putting something white on that would help. But what ? (I don't want to paint it though)

Comment: question needs more details

Comment: What kind of details?

Comment: details about the existing roof, the more details of any kind the better.

Comment: The type of roofing material (tar and gravel, rubber (EPDM), bitumen, etc), thickness of existing insulation (is it rock wool? fiberglass?), if there space for additional insulation. Pictures are also good to add.

Comment: If it's anything like my rowhouse in philadelphia, you would get great improvement if you vented it.

Comment: A bit more info then. Roof is bitumen, with 12cm of fiberglass underneath. I cannot put more insulation except when lowering the ceiling, which is not an option right now.

Answer (score 4):

They make roof "paint" designed for your problem. Will it help, yes, how much depends on a great deal of factors.

[image]

- Roof coating reflects sun's rays to help lower cooling costs
- Roof coating contains insulating ceramic beads
- Urethane for ultimate
  durability

[Product link](http://www.lowes.com/pd_354718-29-5532-1-30_4294934213__?productId=3372930)

Comment: OP stated he did not want to paint it.

Comment: @mike True, I am interrupting that as literal paint (household exterior) and not the process or concept as they did mention putting something white on it.

Comment: Ha didn't know something like this existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A professionally installed spray foam roof is the ultimate solution.  You'd get not only a reflective top coat, but really effective insulation.  Short of that go with the answer https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/30265/5960 and a solar reflective top coat.